# Singular or plural form of the verb?

Tags: verb-agreement

Sorry for the stupid question, but is the following sentence correct:
"The main strength of the paper is the results"? I am always confused by the form of the verb in such sentences, so should the verb "to be" here correspond to the "strength" or to the "results"?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found an answer. In the sentences of the type "X is Y", the subject is X, so the verb should agree with X.